# Sort pages by comments (note board items) count

Tags: 2013, social, social-note

I'm using Note Board (SharePointPortalControls:SocialCommentControl) for comments implementation in my custom page layout which is assignet to each page in Pages library. How can I sort these pages by the count of comments (posts number in note board)?

I'm using SharePoint 2013 Standard license.